# CSS z-index not working when animating a div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone help me make the red div roll OVER the blue paragraph?

http://jsfiddle.net/B3rQR/1/

I tried doing it with z-index, but couldn't make it work:

```
div {
    z-index: 1;
}

p {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is a noob question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can position the `<ul>` or the `<div>` - e.g.

```
ul {
background-color: yellow;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
z-index: 1; /* z-index doesn't work on statically positioned elements */
position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B3rQR/2/

Comment: i did it now... for some reason i'm still not aware, it only lets me aprove an answer 10 minutes after the question. :P

again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Sure, just add `position:relative;` to your div's rules. `z-index` only works on positioned elements.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/B3rQR/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

add `position: relative;` in div